# How can I put a Unity3D game on an Xbox 360 disc?

Tags: unity, xbox360

I've made a simple shooter in Unity that I'd like to play on an Xbox 360. Mass production not required, just a one-off game, completely non-profit. Perhaps burning to a DVD?

Is it a relatively simple procedure to burn the game to disc? I have a nasty feeling the Xbox 360 needs to be chipped. Is this the case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a license for that, one from Microsoft and one from Unity.

> Anyone wishing to deploy to Xbox 360 must sign up via an approved
>   publisher such as Microsoft Studios.

**UPDATE**
if you get and independent developer license, you don't pay anything [link](http://www.xbox.com/en-us/Developers/id)

[Get going with Unity for consoles](http://unity3d.com/unity/multiplatform/consoles) and [Developing Games for
Xbox](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/Developers)

Comment: My dear Sherlock, does one need to part with their well-earned coin to acquire these licenses?

Comment: Just a quick update for everyone else stumbling across this. I've contacted unity sales today asking how to build the game for xbox 360. i'm also not really looking to publish (if i manage to get time and grow the game into something real, maybe, although unlikely), just put it on my xbox 360 for my kid to play with. the reason i made contact with them is because the build settings for xbox 360 are disabled stating my license doesn't cover it, although their license comparison says personal edition allows all platforms? i'll revert with answer as soon as received

Comment: @thorne51 What response did u get from the team?

Answer (score -4):

Considering you aren't interested in licensing, putting the game on one disc shouldn't be hard . It may require a high level dvd disc in order to store your finished game, however, as well as the correct encoding. The encoding should come with Unity's platform abilities.

Comment: Legal issues aside, a stock (unmodded) console will check game discs for a cryptographic signature before allowing them to be played. This signature needs to be provided by the console manufacturer or their tools - Unity won't generate one on its own.

Comment: Legal and cryptographic issues aside, anything you expect for an xbox to run must have been compiled to target the xbox architecture, and must be using the xbox APIs. At the very least you would need the xbox toolchain, headers and libraries. Most likely you can't get those unless you are a licensed xbox developer.